# UITableviewCell unresponsive to custom keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard

I have a custom uitableviewcell with a textfield in it.  To input text into the textfield I am using a custom keyboard.  However, when a keyboard button is pressed, my method fails to update the text in the textfield.  When I check the cell that I've grabbed, I find that it is empty.  Here is the code I use:

```
 VariableCellController *cell = (VariableCellController *)[equationViewController.variableTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[equationViewController.selectedVariableRow intValue] inSection:0]];
```

Where VariableCellController is the uitableviewcell controller and the equationViewController is a property of my CustomNumberPadViewController.

It seems as if my instantiation of equationViewController is not the one actually showing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I added a textfield as a property in my keyboard controller class and passed the handle to the text field to the keyboard controller in the textfielddidbeginediting method.